# how to pass positional parameters to createnativequery jpa java

Tags: java, hibernate, oracle11g, jpa-2.1

I have the following SQL query in my j2ee web app that I am unable to get to work, as-is. The named parameters **sourceSystem** and **sourceClientId** do not appear to get passed to the query, and therefore it does not return any records. I added a watch to the Query object **querySingleView** and it maintained a value of null as the debugger ran through the code. I also inserted a *System.out.println* statement just under the method declaration and confirmed that the correct values **sourceSystem** and **sourceClientId** are being passed to the method signature. I am using NetBeans 8.0, JPA 2.1, running on a JBoss EAP 6.21 server. I have multiple Entities mapped to several tables in an Oracle database.

Here is the query (I should note that the items in the query follow a **schema.table.column** format - not sure if that is part of the problem, but it does work in one test, see my comment and sample below the main query below):

```
    public List<String> searchSingleView (String sourceSystem, String sourceClientId) {
      //Change the underscore character in the source system value to a dash, and   make it uppercase. This is what single view accepts
     if (!sourceSystem.equals("")) {
        sourceSystemSingleView = sourceSystem.replace('_', '-').toUpperCase();
     }    
     String sqlSingleViewQuery = "SELECT DISTINCT " +
     "MDMCUST_ORS.C_BO_CONTRACT.LAST_ROWID_SYSTEM AS POLICY_SYSTEM, " +
     "MDMCUST_ORS.C_BO_CONTRACT.SRC_POLICY_ID AS POLICY_ID, " +
     "MDMCUST_ORS.C_BO_CONTRACT.ISSUE_DT, " +
     "MDMCUST_ORS.C_BO_PARTY_XREF.SRC_CLIENT_ID AS SRC_CLIENT_ID, " +
     "MDMCUST_ORS.C_BO_PARTY_XREF.PERS_FULL_NAME_TXT, " +
     "MDMCUST_ORS.C_BO_PARTY_XREF.ORG_LEGAL_NAME_TXT, " +
     "MDMCUST_ORS.C_BO_PARTY_XREF.ORG_LEGAL_SFX_TXT, " +
     "MDMCUST_ORS.C_BO_PARTY_XREF.ORG_NAME_TXT, " +
     "MDMCUST_ORS.C_BO_PARTY_XREF.SIN_BIN_TEXT, " +
     "MDMCUST_ORS.C_BO_PARTY_XREF.PERS_BIRTH_DT, " +
     "MDMCUST_ORS.C_LU_CODES.CODE_DESCR_EN AS ADDRESS_PURPOSE_CD, " +
     "MDMCUST_ORS.C_BO_PARTY_POSTAL_ADDR.COMPLETE_ADDRESS_TXT, " +
     "MDMCUST_ORS.C_BO_PARTY_POSTAL_ADDR.CITY_NAME, " +
     "MDMCUST_ORS.C_BO_PARTY_POSTAL_ADDR.COUNTRY_NAME, " +
     "MDMCUST_ORS.C_BO_PARTY_POSTAL_ADDR.POSTAL_CD, " +
     "MDMCUST_ORS.C_BO_PARTY_POSTAL_ADDR.STATE_PROVINCE_NAME " +
     "FROM MDMCUST_ORS.C_BO_PARTY_XREF " +
     "LEFT JOIN MDMCUST_ORS.C_BO_PARTY_POSTAL_ADDR ON                MDMCUST_ORS.C_BO_PARTY_POSTAL_ADDR.PARTY_ROWID = MDMCUST_ORS.C_BO_PARTY_XREF.ROWID_OBJECT " +
     "LEFT JOIN MDMCUST_ORS.C_LU_CODES ON MDMCUST_ORS.C_BO_PARTY_POSTAL_ADDR.POSTAL_ADDR_PURPOSE_CD = MDMCUST_ORS.C_LU_CODES.CODE " +
     "LEFT JOIN MDMCUST_ORS.C_BO_PARTY_REL ON MDMCUST_ORS.C_BO_PARTY_XREF.ROWID_OBJECT = MDMCUST_ORS.C_BO_PARTY_REL.FROM_PARTY_ROWID " +
     "LEFT JOIN MDMCUST_ORS.C_BO_CONTRACT ON MDMCUST_ORS.C_BO_PARTY_REL.CONTRACT_ROWID = MDMCUST_ORS.C_BO_CONTRACT.ROWID_OBJECT " +
     "WHERE MDMCUST_ORS.C_BO_CONTRACT.LAST_ROWID_SYSTEM = :sourceSystemSingleView " +
     "AND MDMCUST_ORS.C_BO_PARTY_XREF.SRC_CLIENT_ID = :sourceClientId " +
     "AND MDMCUST_ORS.C_BO_PARTY_POSTAL_ADDR.POSTAL_ADDR_PURPOSE_CD = '56|07' " +
     "AND MDMCUST_ORS.C_BO_PARTY_POSTAL_ADDR.LAST_ROWID_SYSTEM = MDMCUST_ORS.C_BO_CONTRACT.LAST_ROWID_SYSTEM " +
     "ORDER BY MDMCUST_ORS.C_BO_CONTRACT.LAST_ROWID_SYSTEM";

 querySingleView = emSingleView.createQuery(sqlSingleViewQuery);
 querySingleView.setParameter("sourceSystemSingleView", sourceSystemSingleView);
 querySingleView.setParameter("sourceClientId", sourceClientId);
 querySingleViewResult = (List<String>) querySingleView.getResultList();

 return querySingleViewResult;
 }
}
```

However, if I put literal values in the SQL query in place of the positional parameters it works fine (without using the *setParameter* method).

```
WHERE MDMCUST_ORS.C_BO_CONTRACT.LAST_ROWID_SYSTEM = 'ADMIN' " +
"AND MDMCUST_ORS.C_BO_PARTY_XREF.SRC_CLIENT_ID = '0000001234' " +
```

I have looked online but haven't as yet found anything that seems to address this specific question. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, I realized after I submitted my question that my subject heading and the details I give in my question don't actually match. In addition to **name parameters** I was also trying to use **positional parameters**. As follows:  WHERE MDMCUST_ORS.C_BO_CONTRACT.LAST_ROWID_SYSTEM = ?1 " +
"AND MDMCUST_ORS.C_BO_PARTY_XREF.SRC_CLIENT_ID = ?2 "  and then in the setParameter methods **setParameter(1, sourceSystemSingleView)** and **setParameter(2, sourceClientId)**, but that also does not work

Comment: Playing around with the query I got this to work: "WHERE cbc.LAST_ROWID_SYSTEM = '" + sourceSystemSingleView + "'" +
" AND cbpx.SRC_CLIENT_ID = '" + sourceClientId + "'" +. But I am concerned that that might be a SQL injection vulnerability. I hope it isn't as I **really** need to get this resolved. If it is, I welcome any other suggestions. Thanks again!